# PHP - Comparison of array element to input issue

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with the code below, I want to test a user's input against values in a text file. The output of the code works only for the last element of the array (each value of the text file is stored as an element of an array) which succeeds in correctly comparing the input against the array element, however when entering any other element in the array, no 'match' is being made. I want all values to be numeric and only one same value to exist, if more than one, output an error. Thanks guys :)

array.txt has the following contents

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP

if (isset($_REQUEST['attempt']))    {

$users = file('C:/wamp/www/php/comparision/array.txt');
$input = $_POST['input'];

print "Results:";
print '<br></br>';

$x = count($users);

print '<br></br>';
print '<br></br>';

$i = 0;

    while ($i < $x) {

        print $users[$i];
        print $input;
        $truevar = NULL;

        $arrayelement = $users[$i];

            if ($input == $arrayelement) {
                print '<p>';
                echo " It is in the array";
                print '</p>';
                $truevar = $truevar + 1;
            }
            else if ($input != $arrayelement) {
                print '<p>';
                echo " Nope";
                print '<p>';
            }

    print '<br></br>';

    $i = $i + 1;

    }

//Check entries

if ($truevar > 1)   {
    print '<br></br>';
    echo "Multiple entries";
}
else if ($truevar == 1) {
    print '<br></br>';
    echo "Comparison success";
}
else if ($truevar < 1)  {
    print '<br></br>';
    echo "Comparison not successfull";
}   

}
?>

<p>Please enter data</p><br></br>
<form action="compare.php?attempt" method="post"/>
<input type="text" name="input" size="15" value=""  />
<input type="submit" name="carddata" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the file contents? Your question has all the numbers on one line, separated by `-`, not multiple lines. Is that right?

Comment: Try adding the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` option when you call `file()`

Comment: I have edited the file format, each series of numbers are on a new line, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$users = file('C:/wamp/www/php/comparision/array.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Without that option, the newlines that separate the lines in the file are included in the values in `$users`, so the comparisons fail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that you set `$truevar = NULL;` inside the while loop. Like this, the variable always gets reset to NULL with every loop.

You should be fine if you move the `$truevar = NULL` above the `while`-line

Comment: Silly me, this was giving issues with the check on the entries.